# Cannot launch Chromium after rebooting

Tags: ubuntu, chromium

I accidentally switched off my computer earlier. After rebooting, I tried to launch Chromium browser as usual, but it did not open. I got this message:

> [3634:3634:1114/223101:ERROR:process_singleton_linux.cc(240)] readlink(/home/hana/.config/chromium/SingletonLock) failed: Invalid argument
>
> [3634:3634:1114/223101:ERROR:process_singleton_linux.cc(264)] Failed to create /home/hana/.config/chromium/SingletonLock: File exists
>
> [3634:3634:1114/223101:ERROR:chrome_browser_main.cc(1198)] Failed to create a ProcessSingleton for your profile directory. This means that running multiple instances would start multiple browser processes rather than opening a new window in the existing process. Aborting now to avoid profile corruption.

How can I fix this please?

Comment: Have you removed the file that it's complaining about already existing?  `Failed to create /home/hana/.config/chromium/SingletonLock: File exists`

Comment: i couldnt find that file: under /home/hana/.config/chromium/ there is only this:
Crash Reports/ Default/  Dictionaries/  pnacl/